# How to use bootstrap to do a hypothesis test in mixed models

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, mixed-model, bootstrap, likelihood-ratio

I have a mixed model with multiple covariates. I want to test if some of the covariates are insignificant. Since I have mixed model the LR-test will result in a p-value which is too low, hence I want to use bootstrap to do the hypothesis test. Can someone explain the principle in how this could be done? Should I simulate new LR-tests statistics and do something with these or..?

I know how to use bootstrap to make confidence intervals for single parameters, but I'm not sure how to do when I want to remove multiple parameters (i.e. a single covariate) like in this case.

Comment: "Since I have mixed model the LR-test will result in a p-value which is too low" - Why?

Comment: The LR-test assume that observations are independent and have equal variance, but in my model I also have random effects. Pinheiro et al. write that it tends to be anti-conservative when fixed effects are tested.

Comment: How large is your sample?

Comment: 5000 approximately

Comment: I believe the anticonservative issues with likelihood ratio tests fall off with larger sample sizes; 5000 is plenty large.